# How to pass entity or DbSet as parameter?

Tags: generics, linq-to-entities

I would like to pass `dbset` as a generic parameter to make a common method for more queries.
The question is: How to write a generic method which takes `DbSet<MyTable>` as a generic parameter ?
The method contains linq to entities query and return a result. MyTable could be any table of the data model.

I found similar questions but quite complicated. I quess there should be some simple solution for the simplest example.

```
        private IQueryable<string> GetDgData(???)
        {
            var res = dbset.Select(x => x.MyProperty);                 
            return res;
        }
```

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: @NetMage I added an explanation

Comment: In order to access `MyProperty`, the type of `dbset` (shouldn't that be a parameter?) must be of a type that has `MyProperty`. Unless you have a base class or interface shared by all your table types, you would have to use Reflection instead of generics. Or perhaps compiled `Expression` trees.

Comment: @NetMage If I exend all the tables by an interface. How shall the method looks like ?